# How to get current project in nodejs script?

Tags: node.js, firebase

In the cmd terminal, I can run `firebase projects:list` to see the current project selected.
How can I get the current project when I run my nodejs script in the same terminal?

I have a list of projects to work on, first I use firebase use to pick a project to work on. Here is the result from firebase projects:list

```
┌──────────────────────┬──────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ Project Display Name │ Project ID           │ Project Number │ Resource Location ID │
├──────────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ Canvassing           │ canvassing-xx        │ xx             │ us-west1             │
│ EC1                  │ engage-xx            │ xx             │ us-central           │
├──────────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ PVBC                 │ pvbc-xx    (current) │ xx             │ us-west1
```

In this case, the PVBC is the active project.

In my node project, I have a list of functions that need to push to firebase, something like

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
firestore = admin.firestore();

exports.updateState = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  return bloc.updateActivityState(firestore);
});
```

I then use "firebase deploy" to push them to the current project I selected with firebase use.

I also have another set of functions that could do just manipulation from command line, like

```
var fc = require('../firebase_project1_name/config/firebaseConfig.js');
var firebaseConfig = fc.firebaseConfig;
var app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var db = firebase.firestore(app);
var colDistrict = db.collection('districts');
...
```

I put firebase config in file and put them under folder of different project, I need a way to get the current project, like pvbc-xx and replace the firebase_project1_name with the proper name so I can get the config for the current selected project.

Even better, I am thinking if I can get current project info, I don't even need store firebase config in files, I may just get the info current firebase-admin.

Comment: What is your NodeJs script doing? Please add a relevant snippet to your question for more context.

Comment: I have a project with functions to push to firebase and other functions to run in terminal to sync data etc. to firebase from other sources. I need switch between different firebase project. When deploy functions I can use firebase use to set current project. But when I sync data I need use firebase.initializeApp with the current project config data. I want to load config data of the current project set by firebase use.

Comment: You can [initialize Admin SDK without paramters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-without-parameters) like `admin.initializeApp()`. In that case the Admin SDK will use Application Default credentials.

Comment: From what I understand you are working with two separate Firebase projects. If that is the case you will need to have 2 sets of firebase config files and API keys. `firebase use ...` wont give you any config data. `firebase init` will add the necessary files to your current directory. That may override your other project config however.

Comment: Yes, I need different sets of firebase config files. What I am trying to find is a way to pick right config file from the current project I see from the firebase projects:list.

Answer (score 2):

You can [initialize Admin SDK without parameters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-without-parameters) like `admin.initializeApp()` as shown below.

```
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");

const app = initializeApp()

// In case you need the projectId in your code
console.log(app.options.projectId)
```

In this case the Admin SDK will use Application Default credentials for the current project (when using the emulators) and also deploy the functions to the same. You don't have to keeping changing the credentials this way.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds a good solution, but I didn't get right result.
So in terminal, I run firebase projects:list, I got four projects listed. Put your code in test.js and run node test, I got undefined.

Comment: @davidweng can you update your question with the code that you try and how you run it?

Comment: @davidweng you are still passing the credential file to `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);` for my solution don't pass the Firebase config. Also where does it log undefined? I cannot see any console log statement either .

Comment: Code in my question is my code to explain what I want to archive. When I test your solution I used your code exactly. I think I don't get expected result is I don't have a default service account. I need set a default service account to login to default project. Even that work it doesn't solve my problem. AS I explained, I need get the current project from the "firebase use"

Comment: @davidweng essentially when you use `firebase use projectA`, the ADC will be for that project and not `projectB` When you switch the project again, and restart the emulators or try to deploy, it'll be for the selected project. Where are you trying to get the project ID? In the code or in the terminal itself with some Firebase CLI script? Again, if you just want to conditionally select some service account, it might be best to use ADC.

Comment: Thanks Dharmaraj, I want to get the project ID or info in the nodejs code that will be run in the same terminal as I run the firebase use.

Comment: @davidweng then `app.options.projectId` is what you are looking for after initializing the Admin SDK.... or do you need the projectId before it's initilaised?

Comment: Yes, I need projectId before initializing, I need know what project need to be initialized, which is decided by the "firebase use" that will be ran in the terminal before my script.